# What is going on with my Organic Google Traffic?

Tags: seo, search-engine

You can see my Google organic traffic graph attached, as you can see back in the time I have 10K searches and 1K Daily hit but nowadays (for about 2 months or so) I've got only 200-300 unique visitors from Google.

My site is totally unique and the content is not a copy-paste, it is fully written my me and I am updating it Daily.

So, do you have a guess about what's going on with my organic Google traffic? Any help?[image]

Comment: This is impossible for anyone to give anything more than a wild guess.

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed a drop in organic positions for keywords you wish to appear high in Google for? Normally the reason for a drop in organic traffic is directly related to weaker organic rankings.

Have you recently changed anything on the domain? Http to https for example? Webmaster tools is a bit 'dum' and would need both versions submitted.

Ideally you should be tracking organic traffic through Google Analytics not webmaster tools.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the reason while performing these actions:
-Login to your Google Analytics account and check your top organic traffic pages (use in time compare feature to detect pages that caused the drop).
-Check on Google if your main traffic pages are indexed (by typing "site:www.yourwebsite.com" (without quotes) in the search box). Sometimes important pages get removed by admins without appropriate redirection.
-Log in to Google webmaster tools and check if there aren't any manual actions detected: Search Traffic/Manual Actions.
-Also in Google webmaster tools, take a look at Search Traffic/Links to your site. Are there weird websites on the top of the list having hundred or thousand of links pointing to your website? If yes, contact these website to unlink from you, and if you can not co-operate with them, submitt a [disavow request](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en) to Google.
-Check the robots.txt file if there aren't some new rules added to restrict search engine bots' access to your pages.